# linux find command is not taking proper argument

Tags: linux, shell

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -type f ! -name "*.gz" ${FILE_PATTERN} -mtime +${DAYS_AFTER_ARCHIVE}
```

I am trying to execute above command inside the script where `${FILE_PATTERN}` and `${DAYS_AFTER_ARCHIVE}` are the variable provided while executing the script. The variable value for `${FILE_PATTERN}` would be `! -name "*warnings*"`. 
I am looking for executing above command as like below command in script

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -type d ! -name "*warnings*" -mtime +7
```

I am providing file pattern argument as "! -name "*warnings*""
but receiving following error message

```
find: paths must precede expression 
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

suggest on above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
-name "*.gz" ${FILE_PATTERN}
```

has too many option values (this is what usually causes the message shown)

If you use bash or similar, escape the exclamation marks

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \! -path . -type f \! -name "*.gz" ${FILE_PATTERN} -mtime +${DAYS_AFTER_ARCHIVE}
```

> I am providing file pattern argument as "! -name "warnings"" but receiving following error message

You can't combine flags and their values like that. Also, you can't nest `"` like that. So, it could be like

```
 ! -name "$FILE_PATTERN"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BASH you can make use of BASH arrays:

```
# find options
FILE_PATTERN=(! -name "warnings*")

# build the find command
cmd=(find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -type f \( ! -name "*.gz" "${FILE_PATTERN[@}}" \) -mtime +${DAYS_AFTER_ARCHIVE})

# execute the command
"${cmd[@]}"
```

If not using BASH then you will have to **use `eval` with caution**:

```
FILE_PATTERN='! -name "warnings*"'
eval find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -type f ! -name "*.gz" "${FILE_PATTERN}" -mtime +${DAYS_AFTER_ARCHIVE}
```